# Reverse Match Arguments

Tags: python, django

Can someone please explain or direct me to the documentation on the best way to fix this Error?
I have two apps in this project.

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'proj_full' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['project\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

This is my View

```
def CustomerDetailView(request, pk):
   customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
   projects = customer.project_set.all()
   context = {'customer':customer, 'projects':projects}
   return render(request, 'customer/full.html', context)
```

This is my Template

```
<div class="card-body">
            <table class="table-hover table bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Project Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Upload Date</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {% for projects in projects %}
                        <td>{{projects.projName}}</td>
                        <td>{{projects.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{projects.dateCreated}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'proj_full' project.id  %}" class="btn btn-default p-0">View</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

This is my Project App URL List

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
 
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', views.ProjectListView.as_view(), name='proj_list'),
    path('add/', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='proj_add'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='proj_edit'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.ProjectDeleteView.as_view(), name='proj_delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ProjectDetailView, name='proj_full')
]
```

This is my Customer App URL List

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
 
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', views.CustomerListView.as_view(), name='cust_list'),
    path('search/', views.CustomerSearchView.as_view(), name='cust_search'),
    path('add/', views.CustomerCreateView.as_view(), name='cust_add'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.CustomerUpdateView.as_view(), name='cust_edit'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.CustomerDeleteView.as_view(), name='cust_delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.CustomerDetailView, name='cust_full'),
]
```

Comment: can you also list your `ROOT_URLCONF`?

Comment: The NoReverseMatch error is saying that Django cannot find a matching url pattern for the url you've provided in any of your installed app's urls.

Comment: This is the  typical error message if  project.id is empty or not existing in {% url 'proj_full' project.id  %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're having a typo, because you've declared your for loop as `{% for projects in projects %}` reusing the name of the iterable, after changing it you're left with the code below that should work.

Also, don't forget to wrap the `<tr>` tag with your for loop, as you've declared it withou including it.

```
{% for project in projects %}
<tr>
    <td>{{project.projName}}</td>
    <td>{{project.description}}</td>
    <td>{{project.dateCreated}}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'proj_full' project.id  %}" class="btn btn-default p-0">View</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message log, it seems that `project.id` in `<td><a href="{% url 'proj_full' project.id  %}" class="btn btn-default p-0">View</a></td>`  is equal to `'('',)'` and your url path accepts only numbers as arguments